# Mongoose.js update single attribute only if defined/changed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How would I go about changing the attribute 'avatar' only if it is defined?

```
update: function(req, res){
    Student.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, {
      first_name        : req.body.first_name,
      last_name         : req.body.last_name,
      _school           : req.body._school,
      _teacher          : req.body._teacher,
      grade             : req.body.grade,
      language          : req.body.language,
      avatar            : avatar,
      address           : req.body.address,
      city              : req.body.city,
      state             : req.body.state,
      zip               : req.body.zip,
      _guardians        : req.body._guardians,
      updated_at        : req.body.updated_at,
      active            : req.body.active   }, 
    function(err, student){
        if(err) res.render('error', { error: 'Error updating student'});
        res.redirect('/admin/students');
    });
}
```

I am looking for something like this:
var avatar = req.file ? req.file.fieldname : user.avatar;

Then use the var avatar within the update param of 'findOneAndUpdate'

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know your app or its logic, so I dont know how you want to parse and define avatar, so it is up to you (it can be similar to what you posted).

But otherwise, you can do something simple like this.

```
update: function(req, res){
    var options = {
      first_name        : req.body.first_name,
      last_name         : req.body.last_name,
      _school           : req.body._school,
      _teacher          : req.body._teacher,
      grade             : req.body.grade,
      language          : req.body.language,
      address           : req.body.address,
      city              : req.body.city,
      state             : req.body.state,
      zip               : req.body.zip,
      _guardians        : req.body._guardians,
      updated_at        : req.body.updated_at,
      active            : req.body.active   }

    if (avatar) {
        options.avatar = avatar;    
    }

    Student.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, options, 
    function(err, student){
        if(err) res.render('error', { error: 'Error updating student'});
        res.redirect('/admin/students');
    });
}
```